# Unable to access Secure Element on Samsungs S4 and S5 with 4.4.2+

Tags: android, sim-card

I've been working on an app that uses [Secure Element Evaluation Kit (SEEK)](https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/) and the SIM card's Secure Element to store encryption keys and does actual encryption of sensitive data.

So, I've been testing it on various phones/Android versions and found out something interesting. The application suddenly fails when ran on any Samsung with Android 4.4.2+ with the following exception: `java.lang.SecurityException: Access Control Enforcer: access denied: could not open channel`.

Here's a list of phones/Android version and tests:

LG G2 – Android 4.3 – OK
HTC One Max – Android 5.0.2  - OK
Samsung Galaxy S3 – Android 4.3 – OK
Samsung Galaxy S4 – Android 4.2.2 – OK
Samsung Galaxy S4 – Android 4.4.2 – NOT OK
Samsung Galaxy S5 – Android 4.4.2 – NOT OK
Samsung Galaxy S5 – Android 5.0.2 – NOT OK

Could it be a SIM card problem? Our manufacturer has had no prior experience with such matters (the need to access SE from Java code in Android application).

Comment: That is not a standard Android function. Which product and which Android/Java library do you use for accessing the secure element?

Comment: I'm using SEEK for Android - https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/

Comment: I have updated your question with that info.

Answer (score 0):

Check SE related application configuration on all devices: policies in *.te files 
within the /device/manufacturer/device-name/sepolicy directory and BOARD_SEPOLICY variables.
Check trusted credentals installed on device.
Does it work with OS higher than 5.0.2 ?